# How to undo 'setMockInitialValues'

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, sharedpreferences

I'm using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to store some simple data.

When I try to test this, I'm running into an issue.

**Test 1** goes for the happy flow. I use `SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues(data);` to set some initial data and retrieve it just fine.

**Test 2** tests what happens when a `PlatformException` is thrown. I've found to be able to fake this I could hook into the `PlatformChannel` like so:

```dart
sharedPreferencesMethodChannel
        .setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
      throw genericPlatformException;
    });
```

When I only run Test 2, it works as expected, but if I run both tests, test 2 will fail.
If in test 1 i do NOT use `SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues(data);` and run both, test 2 will pass.

So I figured I just need to reset, or undo the setting of the mock values for each test... but how do I do that? It seems like setting them once is permanent.

Answer (score 0):

This just seems not possible to do.

Testing behaviour like `PlatformsExceptions` could be done with the use of mocks.

I've simply allowed setting a mock SharedPreferences on my wrapping class so I'm not interacting with the real `SharedPreferences` while testing.

```dart
class WrapperClass {
  SharedPreferences? _sharedPreferences;

  set mockSharedPreferences(SharedPreferences mock) {
    _sharedPreferences = mock;
  }

  Future<String> getData() async {
    // The real SharedPreferences only gets called if no mock was set
    _sharedPreferences ??= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return _sharedPreferences!.getString('my_key') ?? 'default';
  }
}
```